# AVPlayerLayer SetFrame without animation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avplayer

I have `AVPlayerLayer` in my main screen and i want to add it to `UITableViewCell`(Every time i move to the `ViewController` with the `UITableView`).

This is how i create it:

```
avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:audioPlayer];
[NowPlayingManager setPlayerLayer:avPlayerLayer];
[avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.playerView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.playerView.frame))];
```

This is how i add it to the `UITableViewCell`:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
[[NowPlayingManager getPlayerLayer] setFrame:cell.img.frame];
[CATransaction commit];

[[cell layer] addSublayer:[NowPlayingManager getPlayerLayer]];
```

Now when i back to the main view i use this code:

```
if (avPlayerLayer && [avPlayerLayer superlayer] != [self.playerView layer]) {

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.playerView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.playerView.frame))];

    [CATransaction commit];

    [[self.playerView layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
}
```

And the problem is that when i back from the `UITableView` to the main `ViewController` the `AVPlayerLayer` `setframe` is with animation.

Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: All you need to do is [avPlayerLayer removeAllAnimations]; just after the frame is set

Comment: any fix on this??